# how can I able to see what messages are currently processing in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am new to celery and rabbitmq and I am trying to find out when I send a message from celery to rabbitmq why it is not showing up in the rabbitmq queue but the messages gets processed?

[Here is a list of queue that have been created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOwiH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default message delivery mode is `nack =true`. That means when a producer sends a message to rabbitMQ server, it will buffer it in the message queue. But if there is any active consumer, then the message will be removed from the queue as soon as the message is sent. The other mode of delivery is manual acknowledging of the message. for that you should use `nack=false`. So the message is removed from the queue only when the consumer acknowledge the message.